# Unobtrusive validation contact person

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, unobtrusive-validation

While working with jquery unobtrusive validation in my ASP.NET MVC 3 project I noticed something in the `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` source code that looks like a bug to me. I fixed it for my needs, but I want to

1) confirm that it is indeed a bug, rather than a feature which application is totally unclear to me;

2) if the bug is confirmed, contribute to the development of the next version of the library so that there is no more this bug in the future.

Any ideas on to whom I should send or where I should post my findings?

If someone is interested in the issue itself, please leave a comment and I'll update the post with the detailed information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

where did you find this jquery ? i know jquery.validate but not this one...

If you find it on the jquery website maybe you can use the [signal bugs form](http://bugs.jquery.com/newticket).

Comment: it's Microsoft's library for MVC 3.0. It uses jquery validate, but adds some MVC specific features to it to make live easier.

Comment: This could help indeed. Thanks!